# ¿Hay alguna manera para que una página no se almacene en el caché?

Tags: html5, web, cache

Mi pregunta es simple:

¿Hay alguna forma para que mi web no se almacene en el caché?. Hago constantes cambios y la previsualización que hacen los dispositivos es de la primera vez que entran, es decir que no se ven los cambios realizados a posteriori.

¿Alguien podría echarme un cable?

Comment: Recuerda que debes agregar el código con el que has probado, qué no te ha funcionado o qué errores te muestra el navegador. Pásate por la sección [Cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Answer (score 2):

En la primera respuesta te indican cómo no almacenar el HTML, pero un problema que suelo tener comunmente es que se cachean los CSS y los JS.

Para los archivos CSS:

```
<link rel="preload" href="assets/css/styles.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'"/>
```

Para los JS:

```
<script>
    $.getScript({ url: "assets/js/index.js", cache: false }); //Archivos JS
</script>
```

También te recomiendo que para el proceso de desarrollo deshabilites el caché de tu navegador, en mi caso siempre uso `Chrome`, le das en `inspeccionar`, en la nueva ventana que se abre seleccionas `Network` y en la parte superior verás un checkbox que dice `Disable cache`, lo activas y ya. **Esto va a funcionar siempre y cuando tengas la consola de desarrollador (DevTools) abierta.**

Answer (score 1):

Puedes introducir una de las siguientes etiquetas en el `head`, entre las etiquetas:

`<head>

</head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Con esto, el navegador no tiene en cuenta el cache que ha guardado.

Con `PHP` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php
  header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
  header("Expires: Sat, 1 Jul 2000 05:00:00 GMT"); // Se usa una fecha en tiempo pasado
?>
```

Esto resetea el caché en todos los navegadores que ingresen a tu sitio web.

**Fuente:** [Raiola Networks](https://raiolanetworks.es/blog/forzar-leer-el-cache-del-navegador-web/)