# ¿Cómo actualizar una imagen al recargar la página, sin usar javascript?

Tags: html5, img

Tengo una página web realizada con html5, css3 y php8 con un formulario para cambiar la imagen del usuario. El programa hace todo correctamente,  pero al volver a cargar la página, aparece la imagen anterior.

¿Cómo puedo actualizar la imagen al recargar la página? Estoy usando html5.

La imagen se muestra con un enlace normal. Ejemplo con una página html mínima:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="midir/mi_imagen.jpg"> 
</body>
</html>
```

Un programa en el servidor modifica la imagen midir/mi_imagen.jpg pero cuando recargo la página, permanece la imagen vieja.

Comment: Debes dar algo más de contexto y de código.  Por otro lado, el nombre de la imagen se mantiene luego del cambio o también cambias el nombre?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Hay alguna manera para que una página no se almacene en el caché?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286029/hay-alguna-manera-para-que-una-p%c3%a1gina-no-se-almacene-en-el-cach%c3%a9)

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a la comunidad. Te sugiero hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas las normas del sitio. Respecto a tu pregunta, tal vez [esta información](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286029/hay-alguna-manera-para-que-una-p%c3%a1gina-no-se-almacene-en-el-cach%c3%a9/286031#286031) pueda darte una idea.

Comment: Un truco que suele funcionar es, desde php, generar un número aleatorio y añadirlo al final de la imagen, por ejemplo $r = rand(); $n = "midir/mi_imagen.jpg?v=".$r; y luego la pones en el src, así como el nombre de la imagen cambia, fuerzas a que la cargue realmente y no sea desde caché.

Comment: He modificado la pregunta agregando algo de código html. El comentario de track3r responde mi pregunta. Gracias